# Hot create a page like this?

Tags: android, android-studio

[i want to create a screen like in that picture 3 columns screen with different types of services with transparent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKpAg.jpg)tell me which layout and which views are used in it ?

Comment: https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve it with [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout) inside Scrollview. It's also can be done with ConstraintLayout. If you have dynamic data, look at RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Comment: Thank You so Much